# Use of electronics in 49cc 2 stroke dirt bike engine

Tags: engine, maintenance, car, flywheel

[image]

The picture is taken from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVsPyLluTAM&ab_channel=AmericanTech). Are there any electronics in this 49cc 2 stroke dirt bike engine.  Are electronics responsible for the ignition timing of spark plug? Or, is the flywheel (that has magnet on one side) help in the ignition timing of spark plug? And, is the oil injection timed as well in this engine and how it is timed perfectly? I need some help in understanding this.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I have reworded the question for the OP.  There is surely no need to close a question just because a presumption was made.  I am sure there are plenty of other questions where the OP presumed something was the case and were corrected in an answer.

Comment: When you asked about the oil injection, did you mean fuel?

Comment: @HandyHowie that's a good edit. Upvoted and retracted close vote.

Answer (score 2):

There are no electronics used on this engine.  The spark is produced and timed by the magnet passing the HT coil.  The output of the HT coil goes directly to the spark plug.

[image]

Comment: The electronics  in the black casing shown in your picture actually. But, I have no idea why we need that. And, what about the fuel injection timing ? Are there any :)

Comment: Got a smilar video here at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Khc7-Epp-wA&ab_channel=GDEngineering-RestorationVideos  . At 2:43 in that video, it shows he is taking off the electronics :)

Comment: The black casing in that picture is just an HT coil.  No electronics.

Comment: Same in the second video, just an HT coil and spark plug cable and an extra wire for killing the spark.

Comment: There may be a language issue here. To be clear: the devices shown in the video (HT coil, spark plug cables) are _electrical_ but they are not _electronic_. The two words do not have the same meaning.